# Programmatic sub-menus on Tablets works different in different Android versions, but no difference to Phones?

Tags: android

**In a regular Android app, I can't make onCreateOptionsMenu addSubMenu work on Tablet HAXM Nougat  API25   x86 Android 7.1.1 or later, the sub menu exists in the menu rows, but nothing happens (no submenu is shown). Phones and elder versions of Tablets works.**

- All tablets up to HAXM Marshmallow API23 x86 Android 6.0 (Google APIs) onCreateOptionsMenu addSubMenu works fine
- Phone HAXM devices like Nexus 5X, Pie API 28 x86 Android 9.0 (Google Play) works fine
- My Samsung J6 phone (API 26 Android 8.0.0) works fine
- My Samsung TAB4 (SM-T230) Tablet (API 19 Android 4.4.2) works fine
- **But any Tablet HAXM Nougat API 25  x86 Android 7.1.1 or later do not work, the sub menu exists in the menu rows, but nothing happens (no submenu is shown) if the sub menu is selected**

This is a simplified version of the Java code:

```
private static final int MENU_SEARCH                    = 0x04;
private static final int MENU_OPEN                      = 0x08;
private static final int MENU_SAVE                      = 0x09;
private static final int MENU_SAVE_AS_STD               = 0x11;
private static final int MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_ALL           = 0x12;
private static final int MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_CHART         = 0x13;
private static final int MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_BALANCE       = 0x14;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    {
    menu.clear();
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_SEARCH, Menu.NONE, "MENU_SEARCH");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_OPEN, Menu.NONE, "MENU_OPEN");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_SAVE, Menu.NONE, "MENU_SAVE");
    menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_SAVE_AS_STD, Menu.NONE, "MENU_SAVE_AS_STD");
    Menu menuSaveAsStd = menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST + MENU_SAVE_AS_STD).getSubMenu();
    menuSaveAsStd.clear();
    menuSaveAsStd.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_ALL, Menu.NONE, "MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_ALL");
    menuSaveAsStd.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_BALANCE, Menu.NONE, "MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_BALANCE");
    menuSaveAsStd.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_CHART, Menu.NONE, "MENU_SAVE_AS_STD_CHART");
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**I wonder if it is a Android tablet API version policy issue or if it is a HAXM bug?** (I will go and buy myself a newer Tablet, but does anyone knows?)

Any suggestion on how to handle the issue if it is a change in policy? In Android TV there are no menus by policy for instance. Call a popup menu? Or any better idea? (There is no documentation on this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Well this logics works and we need to adapt to the design of the OS.

```
    boolean bHwNoSubmenues = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);
    boolean bHwChromeium = (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management"));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        bHwNoSubmenues = false; // Elder Xlarge screens work with Submenues
    if (bHwChromeium) 
        bHwNoSubmenues = true;
```

Then design flat menus or in trees after the circumstances.